# Как использовать getConnections() в Meteor 1.2.1 вместо this.connections для получения clientAddress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

До того как обновить Meteor до версии 1.2.1 я использовал `this.connection.clientAddress` для получения IP-адреса клиента, после обновления получил в консоли ошибку и такое сообщение:  `connections property is deprecated. Use getConnections() method`... Так каким же образом мне использовать рекомендуемый **getConnections** ?

Answer (score 1):

Использую 1.1.3, на 1.2.1 проверить возможности нет, но тем не менее, этот код должен работать на 1.2.1:

```
Meteor.onConnection(function(conn){ 
  console.log(conn) //В этом объекте должны быть нужны для вас данные.
});
```